# apache camel java config referencing a router from other router

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am in the process of converting apache camel routes from XML to Java based. In XML I can reference a router from another router using a ref attribute like the small code snippet below:

```
<route>
     <from ref="process"/>
     <to ref="logging"/>
</route>

<route>
    <from ref="logging"/>
    <to uri="bean:xyz?method=hello"/>
</route>
```

Now, I can't find an option on how can I refer a router from other router if I use Java.

```
@Bean (name = "loggingRouter")
    RoutesBuilder loggingRouter() {
            return new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    from("xyz")
                        .bean(abc, "log");
                }
            };
        }
```

I want to refer the above created route in Java in other routes. How can I do it? I am on spring boot 1.4.3 and camel 2.18.1.

Updating the question as i could not add the code snippet in comments,

We have multiple RoutesBuilder in java class, and we create each based on condition

```
@Bean (name = "abc")
    @ConditionalOnProperty (name = "someproperty", havingValue = "true")
    RoutesBuilder directSMSRouter() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:sendSMS")
                    .bean(abc, "sendSmsMessage");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean (name = "xyz")
    @ConditionalOnExpression ("'${someproperty1}'.equalsIgnoreCase('true') ||" +
                              "'${someproperty2}'.equalsIgnoreCase('true') ||" +
                              "'${someproperty3}'.equalsIgnoreCase" +
                              "('true') || '${someproperty4}'.equalsIgnoreCase('true') ")
    RoutesBuilder directEmailRouter() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:sendEmail")
                    .bean(xyz, "sendMessage");
            }
        };
    }
```

We can create multiple Routes in configure method, but my issue is how can i refer one route create in RoutesBuilder bean in other route which is different RoutesBuilder

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this java code is creating a RouteBuilder. I don't think you can have multiple RouteBuilders in your application. What your are doing inside configure method is creating routes. You can write as many routes you want inside configure  method. You can write another line, something like.

```
from("blah blah").to("xyz")
```

And that should serve the process. 
Take a look at [Spring RouteBuilder](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-spring/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spring/SpringRouteBuilder.html&ved=0ahUKEwjn-deN3Z_TAhVMDxoKHexzCroQFggcMAA&usg=AFQjCNEJLMOrHw0a5LM9qkV5miRE86MlAg)

Comment: i have updated the question, issues is reference one route created in RoutesBuilder in other route in different RoutesBuilder, not about creating multiple routes in configure method